# How to insert a HTML into Excel

Tags: html, excel, gis, vba

I have a map on a website which changes with time (interactive) and I would like to insert it on the excel sheet.

I am using this code but it does not show the HTML:

```
Private Sub Mapit()
URL = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1) //Here there is written the link to the website that want to show on excel
Sheets("sheet1").Pictures.Insert(URL).Select End Sub
```

Is that possible? I guess that Sheets("sheet1").**Pictures**.Insert(URL).Select is the problem but I am not able to find which is the correct way.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You are almost there. No need for `.Select`

```
Sub Mapit()

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png"
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (URL)

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Mapit()

    Dim URL As String
    URL = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Sheets("sheet1").Pictures.Insert (URL)

End Sub
```

**Updated after comments :**

Insert Userform > Goto toolbox > Additional COntrols > 
Select Microsoft Web Browser > OK

Drag the control to userform

Now on userform paste below code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate ("www.google.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Santosh and thanks a lot for your time but the problem is that what I want is to show to be able to have the complete website on my excel sheet.
I dont know if it is possible to get that. Is it?

Comment: @yke I have updated the answer. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I think it is that. YES, but I am getting an error in 

Me.WebBrowser1 (ERROR OR DATA MEMBER NOT FOUND)

Comment: Didn't know this was possible! Thanks :) still useful after all these years

Comment: Related SO question about Microsoft Web Browser Control:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024440/how-to-make-microsoft-web-browser-object-work-in-excel-2016