# How to make Microsoft Web Browser object work in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

When I try to insert it, I constantly get the "Cannot insert object" error. It seems to be a known issue with former Excel versions, but I couldn't find any support for 2016.

Has anyone been able to make this work?

Here are screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @SilentRevolution the error happens independent of code. I'm having trouble adding the object to the spreadsheet. You can find screenshots below:

Comment: I see no screenshots, please add them to your question by editing it.

Comment: sorry about that: 
http://i.imgur.com/GZLv1cF.png 
http://i.imgur.com/NJYuCDw.png

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be intentional behaviour from Excel 2013 onwards. From [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2793374):

> This issue occurs because some scriptable controls are made obsolete
>   in Office 2013 for security reasons. This is by design, and these
>   errors are expected.

There is a workaround posted in that article which involves editing the registry to make these controls work again.

(The KnowledgeBase article was originally linked from [this Microsoft community thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-customize/embedded-web-browser-in-excel-2013-fails-to-appear/af83ceff-69fa-43fe-a58a-2b3a5fffbe1d?db=5&auth=1) from 2014)

Answer (score 4):

Fix ActiveX Controls (such as the Web Browser) in Excel (Office 2013-16)

Navigate to

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}]
```

"Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000

Navigate to in order to find the GUID of the control you are trying to fix (I was needing to fix the Web Browser control thus opened its GUID).
[reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2793374)

Open the desired GUID and set dword to 0 (vs. 1024 (400H))

Answer (score 4):

Context of the solution:
-Win 10 version 1803 / 64bit os
-Excel O365 ClicktoRun version 1806 10228.20080 / 64bit

The registry is located at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}
```

And set the "Compatibility Flags" DWord to 0

Note: To reenable the blocking feature set Dword value back to "400"

[Killbit option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP11O.png)

This article also helped: [Cannot insert certain scriptable ActiveX controls into Office 2013 documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793374/cannot-insert-certain-scriptable-activex-controls-into-office-2013-doc)

And this one: [Security Settings for COM objects in Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4058123/security-settings-for-com-objects-in-office)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the file path for me: `Win 10 x64 Build 1803 (17134.407)`

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\COM Compatibility\{25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}
```

Hopefully, that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

"Here is the file path for me: Win 10 x64 Build 1803 (17134.407)
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\COM Compatibility{25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"

You need to set the compatibility flags to 0 for all the DWord entries in this Key not just the one mentioned above - then it works