# How can I embed HTML file in excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am working on a project which requires me to add a chart store in HTML file into excel. The MS web browser Active X control does not allow me to add a web browser. If I do that using VBA, it gives me some error related to not displaying Active Content. Please provide me some assistance on this. I have used IE object in VBA, but it opens the HTML file in IE.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to take the Microsoft web browser app and insert it into excel cells. This will allow you to insert the HTML.

Please note excel is not made to handle HTML and as such you won't be able to go in-depth with you HTML. Rather use different programs like MT Blocks to get the desired result.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/html-into-excel.387722/

Comment: Thanks, Devon for your response. I tried all this but it didn't work for me. May you recommend any free Excel add-in that can make Excel add HTML widget in a file.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024440/how-to-make-microsoft-web-browser-object-work-in-excel-2016