# Error inserting Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX Object on Excel 365

Tags: excel, activex

I'm having some trouble. I cannot embed the ActiveX Microsoft Web Browser control in an Excel sheet as desired. Tried a few others controllers and works flawless but Web Browser isn't. Only getting the Cannot Insert Object error.

Version: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20326) 64 bits

Does anyone know what might be going on here and/or what a solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Microsoft Web Browser object work in Excel 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024440/how-to-make-microsoft-web-browser-object-work-in-excel-2016)