# i'm not able to export html elements from html to excel(.xlsm)

Tags: javascript, php, excel, templates

I want to **export html elements or form to excel(.xlsm)** template in *php* or *javascript* just as in this **image** file. I searched for possible solutions but all I get was to export table data to excel, I can use that too but I need the input fields as they are just as in
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/celNu.png) image.

Till now I have user basic code to export a table into excel but when I change the extenstion of the file then excel says it is a corrupted file, the code I used is like:

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xlsm':'excel_data.xlsm';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {type: dataType});
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

This code returns the excel file with or without the custom name.

Comment: This might be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223255/how-to-insert-a-html-into-excel

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but my project is based on php and javascript......can you have reference in this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are creating is TSV (in this case SSV) - Tab Separated Values, it's not xlsm. Just save it as .tsv and excel will open that.